# Why are sometimes the subject and object in the same case?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Er ist ein sehr lustiger Clown.

I am confused by the above sentence. Why is "lustiger Clown" in nominative case? I think it should be einen lustiger Clown because "lustiger Clown" is the object of ist.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that piece *ein sehr lustiger Clown* isn't an object. It's a predicative expression. Some verbs as *sein, werden, bleiben, gelten als, scheinen, erscheinen, wirken* and a few more are so called *Kopulaverben.*

They take a predicative, which is *a description of the subject,* and thus, has to be in the same case.

In German, you have to learn for each and every verb which cases it takes. The majority of verbs take an accusative object and may take an optional dative object, but there's also verbs which take no accusative object but only an optional dative object, some verbs which take accusative and optional genitive, some verbs with genitive, and some verbs even have two accusative objects. And, there's also those verbs which take predicatives, either in nominative or caseless.

Comment: Good explanation. Maybe it makes sense to motivate this behavior. I always thought, the reason for _sein_ to not take an object is that you could swap the predicative expression and the subject: _Ein sehr lustiger Clown ist er_. But I am not 100% sure if this is the "real" reason for this behavior.

Comment: The first piece in a German main clause is the topic. Anything may go there so you can't deduce anything from that.

Comment: Isn't _Ein sehr lustiger Clown_ the subject in that phrase?

Comment: No. The subject is still *er*. You can deduce that in this case because a pronoun cannot be a description of the subject.

Comment: Thanks! Learnt a lot today :)

Comment: @Janka: Your claim is false. It has become topic of this question: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/71863/1487